# Use the abstract class of one project in another c#

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have two projects Project A and Project B.In project B there is a class TC which is an abstract class and in that class there is an abstract method CanSave().
I have added the reference of project A in project B.
In project B I want to use the abstract method CanSave as override of Project A. So one way is just simply add the class of Project A as a parent class of Project B and then use it as a override method.But the problem is  that there is already a class from which the class of project B is inheriting.So i cannot use it because cannot use multiple base classes.
What will be the solution so that I can use the abstract class in the Project B

Snippet
Project A
    public abstract class TC
    {
         protected abstract bool CanSave(object parameter);
    }

Project B
    public class OP:CM(Already there is a base class)
    {
        //Want to use CanSave here
    }

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you could create another class(Lets say TTC) in Project B which inherits TC, then create an object of TTC in OP class

Answer (score 1):

If it's abstract method (without implementation) I would suggest declaring interface. You can inherit from one class, but from multiple interfaces (independently whether you already inherit from class).

Comment: Ya that is the problem that it contains other non abstract methods with implementation.

Comment: Yes, ok, but you can encapsulate method `CanSave()` in interface (and remove it from your class). Then all classes, that use this method will have to implement that interface, but then you can add this interface to your new project and you can inherit from it along with other classes.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your abstract class TC to and interface and then you'll be able to derived from it in class OP:

```cs
public interface ITC
{
    bool CanSave(object parameter);
}

public class OP: CM, ITC
{
    public bool CanSave(object parameter) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot convert it into interface because there are other different non abstract methods implemented in the class.I cannot convert it into interface because in interface there will be no implementations.

Comment: do you need all non-abstract methods of TC in the derived class?

Comment: Yes and I cannot change the implementation of TC because so many other classes are also using the class TC and its methods.So changing something in TC can affect other classes also which are using TC.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to extract `CanSave` method logic to a static method and use it in both projects. Otherwise you have to keep instance of class `TC` inside your `OP` instance

Comment: :There are so many  other classes which are using the same abstract method CanSave so I cannot change that functionality.

Comment: @Ritesh You have to make changes only inside CanSave method. There is no impact at all for classes that use it

Answer (score 0):

you could create another class(Lets say TTC) in Project B which inherits TC

```
public class TTC: TC
{
    ...
}
```

then create an object of TTC in OP class

```
public class OP:CM
{
    private TTC ttcobject;
    //you can inject it
    public OP(TTC _ttc){
        this.ttcobject = _ttc;
        // or just initialize it here
        // ttcobject = new TTC();
    }

    public bool CanSave(object parameter)
    {
        return ttc.CanSave(parameter;
    }
}
```